# Add/Remove elements depending of window width

Tags: jquery, append, hide, show

I want to add or remove elements depending on the screen dimension.
I'm trying to remove the items I don't want to be showed and append the one that I would like to appear.

With this, the elements are getting removed but nothing's getting appended.

I get the expected result when using `.hide()` and `.show()`, but I would rather remove them from the DOM.

Does someone know a way to solve this?
Thanks

JS:

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {

  var three = $('#three');
  var four = $('#four');
  var five = $('#five');
  var wrapper = $('.grid-wrapper');

  if($(window).width() < 769) {
    five.detach();
    four.detach();
    wrapper.append(three)
  }
  else if($(window).width() > 2018) {
    three.detach();
    four.detach();
    wrapper.append(five)
  }
  else {
    three.detach();
    five.detach();
    wrapper.append(four)
  }

}).resize();
```

Comment: You should consider using css media queries for this, not js, so that the browser does it natively.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the variables `var three =` etc are set/reset each time you resize.

Once you remove `#three` it won't exist any more, so the subsequent call `var three = $("#three")` will give an empty jquery collection.

If you move these outside the event handler, then the browser will keep them in memory when you .remove / .detach them, so they can be re-added later.

Cut down example:

```js
var one = $("#one");  // found as not yet removed
one.remove();

$("#two").remove();

$("button").click(() => {
    var two = $("#two");  // not found as previously removed
    
    $("#wrapper").append(one);  // stored above
    $("#wrapper").append(two);  // nothing to add
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click me</button>
<hr />
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="one">one</div>
  <div id="two">two</div>
</div>
```